# GLKMatrix4 (and other similar) missing in swift?

Tags: opengl-es, swift, ios8

I'm having an issue creating a 4X4 openGL matrix in swift. I have imported the following which worked in Obj-C:

```
import UIKit
import GLKit
import OpenGLES
```

`GLKMatrix4` is not available, however I have access to other GL math resources, `GLKMathDegreesToRadians()` for instance.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: what is the issue exactly?

Comment: None of the GLmatrix initializer methods are available. I am attempting to use GLKMatrix4Make but get an unresolved identifier warning from the compiler.

Comment: the swift equivalent of `GLKMatrix4Make()` is `GLKMatrix4()`. have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that initially and fell back to trying to use the former. I see other GLKMatrix* functions in the autocomplete but nothing that returns a matrix. Most of them return void. I thought perhaps the GLMath components weren't coming in with the GLKit import, but as I mentioned before GLKMathDegreesToRadians() works as expected.

Comment: Also, the Swift documentation for GLKMatrix4 is incomplete as of yet.

Comment: you're right actually I'm having the same problem. `GLKMatrix4` appears to be a module not a type

Comment: I just had the good sense to check the apple forums and I guess this is a known issue with Swift not yet supporting C unions. Looks like we'll have to wait for the next Beta.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using GLKMath from GLKit in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622475/using-glkmath-from-glkit-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected in playground and yields a 4x4 matrix Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)

```
import GLKit

let someMatrix: GLKMatrix4 = GLKMatrix4Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```